# How to choose platform?

Tags: java, android, .net, platform

I just completed my post graduation and I know core java, advance java and oracle and little bit android, so to start my carrier i have option to choose java/.net platform. I am also interested to learn .net so which choice is better to learn .net or continue with just java platform? give me your suggestions.

Comment: There is no good answer for that. None is better than any other.

Comment: If you're interested to learn .NET then I don't see how programming only in Java is going to help with that.  Hint: There's no reason why you can't do both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learning is always a good thing. There is no such thing as the one language to rule them all.

Comment: But i need help to start my career and i have two choices either learn struts, hibernet and spring and continue with java or learn .net and continue with .net. which one is better?

Comment: There is no such thing as a better language. A language is a tool to be used. You don't ask either: "Which is better: a hammer or a screwdriver?"

Comment: the one who fits you better, you like better, whatever... you have to decide

Comment: Just some idea how I got started with my career: first I wrote Delphi combined with some LUA, then Java ME, Java, an Apache module in C/C++, an application in JS/HTML5, Hadoop application (Java), another C++ code for mobile phones, then an App for iOS, BlackBerry and Android. In between some Python, Perl and BASH scripting.